# Unable to modify items in the collection Keys of Forms.ImageList.Images

Tags: c#, winforms, imagelist

I'm using my first dotnet `TreeView` and I have a problem with `ImageList` Keys.

When I write this code :

```
int i;
i = MyIL.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.CheckedItemBitmap, Color.White);
MyIL.Images.Keys[i] = "Checked";
```

The `key` is not written. I mean that `MyIL.Images.Keys[i]` is still empty after that code. It looks like that it is read only. But the documentation says that one can set values in it.

This is a problem because I want to use this specific overloaded `ImageList.Images.Add()` function, that doesn't let me specify the key value.

This is not the end of the world, but any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Keys` property is read-only. The key is normally something that is set when you add the item to the collection, and sure enough, there is an overload of `Images.Add` that accepts a custom key. So I would use that overload, and set the transparent colour in a separate call:

```
Properties.Resources.CheckedItemBitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
MyIL.Images.Add("Checked", Properties.Resources.CheckedItemBitmap);
```

Comment: I'll take your workaround. But Keys could be a read-only collection object, while its items could be writable.

Comment: It would be highly unusual to change the key of an item in a collection after it's been added. It would be like changing the index. Imagine `ImageCollection` is a dictionary, if that helps.

Comment: So, this is by design ? I'm setting a value, I get no compile error and no runtime exception, and no effect at all. Great. Would it be too much to ask for some king of container flag that would tell me that sometimes I get a read only reference, a frozen subclass object, or a useless deep copy (or on the fly creation) of an inner collection ?

Comment: So, this is by design ? I'm setting a value, I get no compile error and no runtime exception, and no effect at all. Great. I would have appreciated some kind of container flag that would have told the container that it is a in read only mode, or even a useless deep copy (or on the fly creation) of an other object's inner collection.

Comment: I agree that would be nice, but WinForms hasn't been actively developed for a number of years now and there's lots of old code that doesn't conform to the latest framework conventions.